# react navigation not rendering screens

Tags: react-native

I currently building a simple react native app which has two screens. I am using a react navigation to navigate between screens and when I tried following this guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html, It doesn't render anything, just displaying a blank screen. Maybe I'm missing something that's why it doesn't render. Here's my js files:

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Login from './src/components/screens/login';
import Order from './src/components/screens/order';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: Login,
    Order: Order
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  }
);

export default class Sales extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <App />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

login.js

```js
class Login extends Components {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false,
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Button title="Login"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Order')}
        />
      </View >
    );
  }
}
```

order.js

```js
class Order extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button 
            title="Create Order"
            color='#65639E'
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html#wrapping-appcontainer-in-a-view-without-flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    export default class Sales extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <View>
        <App /> // This code right here
       </View>
     );
  }

 }
```

You're rendering `<App />` but you don't have an App Component. Maybe try using `<Login />`

Comment: I forgot to include const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

Comment: @ana What's the url when you run the project?

Comment: how to find the url? did you mean 10.0.2.2:8081 ?

Comment: When you open the project in the browser? What's the url? Is it `http://localhost:8081` or `http://10.0.2.2:8081`? Try adding /Login in the url because the initial route name is 'Login'

Comment: when I run the project in the browser with both http://localhost:8081 /Login and http://10.0.2.2:8081/Login this was shown: cannot Get /Login

Comment: I just found why it's not rendering, I changed the render part in app.js export default class Sales extends Component {
  render() {
    return <App />;
    );
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: Login,
    Order: Order
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  }
);

export default class Sales extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <App /> // this is worng.. As there is no app component. Never wrap 
   //AppNavigator inside a view
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The right thing should be. Just trying to tempelate your requirement.

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Login Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Order extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Order Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: Login,
  Order: Order
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

I hope I'm able to make my point. If any confusion do mention in the comment. More than happy to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The way i fixed this for myself was by removing `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` from the main app container.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Login from './src/components/screens/login';
import Order from './src/components/screens/order';


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    Login: Login,
    Order: Order
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
}
);

class Sales extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <AppNavigator />  --> pass here your navigation 
        </View>
    );
}

}

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```